# Close file descriptor by number

Tags: perl

My Perl program executes lvs which gives the warning

> File descriptor 63 (pipe:[117387]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent
>   PID 12053: perl

because the program calling my Perl program left this descriptor open.  I can't change the calling program, but is there a way for me to close the filehandle in Perl?  I tried:

```
'close 63 or die "close failed";
```

which dies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`close` from [POSIX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX) can do that.

```
use POSIX qw( );
POSIX::close(63);
```